# How to run long task while flutter app is in background

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background, workmanagers

I'm looking for a way to run dart code in the background when my app is active and continue it when the app is put in the background or is terminated.

I will make many API call and database management. This task could take 10min to 45min or more if the user has a bad network.
My users need to see the task progression, so when a task is launched, I would see its execution immediately.

I've tested flutter isolates, but it seems that they are paused/terminated when the app is paused or killed by the system or by the user.

I've tested flutter_workmanager but in iOS background processing only run in background and stop when the app goes in foreground. In addition, the system decides the best moment to run the callback launched by my code... So my user can start the task and never see it begin...

What can I test now :'( ?

(I'm curious to heard answers even if it's in native: kotlin, Swift)

Comment: This just sounds like the wrong approach.  A mobile app should not need to perform long, complex tasks.  Do that on a server where processing power, battery and network is not a concern

Comment: It cannot be done on server side because it's to sync an offline database for a specific business need.

Comment: The native feature on iOS is a [BGprocessingTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtask) but I doubt that even this will give you 45 minutes of runtime. ios specifically discourages this kind of work.

Comment: The bad things about BGProcessingTask is that iOS decide when it should start and it could take many hours... In addition, when app go foreground this task is stoped. That require a code logique duplication (foreground / background).

But because of the first bad things, I cannot continue to use that.

Comment: As I said, your use case isn't a good fit for mobile.  You need to rethink your approach so that your data can be delivered efficiently to the mobile app with minimal processing required.  If you cannot avoid a long, expensive task then it is better to do this in the foreground and show a message to the user asking them to keep the app open until the sync is complete

Comment: Okay, if it's the right way I understand i will apply that.
I was confused maybe by other app like netflix which download film in background even app is killed. But it's different because it's just file downloading and not complexe task.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Phones work different while charging. Many restrictions are released.